# jQuery .slideToggle() to also close other tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two sections, each with 3 divs, opening on slideToggle. How can I close the other 2 divs in each section when 1 is open?

https://jsfiddle.net/koteva/mdx20uqe/2/

```
   <div id="stage1">

   <h2 id="location-1">Location</h2>
   <div id="location-1t">grjryjj</div>              

   <h2 id="jersey-1">JERSEY </h2>
   <div id="jersey-1t" style="display: none;">  ighlgkiuluil   </div>

   <h2 id="details-1">details</h2>
   <div id="details-1t" style="display: none;">fykyuk    </div>

   </div>           

   <div id="stage2">

   <h2 id="location-2">Location2</h2>
   <div id="location-2t">grjryjj</div>              

   <h2 id="jersey-2">JERSEY2 </h2>
   <div id="jersey-2t" style="display: none;">  ighlgkiuluil    </div>

   <h2 id="details-2">details2</h2>
   <div id="details-2t" style="display: none;">fykyuk   </div>

   </div>
```

Comment: Well, if you have 20 headers and blocks, will you write 20 near-the-same click handlers? If "yes", you can add hiding all other elements in every click handler. If you don't want to write this bad code, then it's time to use, for example, classes to hide.

Comment: I acctualy have around 60 headers and blocks - do not know another solution, you are more than welcomed to share..

Comment: Add a class ".active" which is added on click and removed from all others. the active can act as a flag for the slide toggle

Comment: Something like [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdx20uqe/5/). The only "bad" place is `.next()`, but it's still better than tons of code.

Comment: @tanya inside only local stage: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdx20uqe/7/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your jsFiddle, you could replace all your js code with

```
$('h2').click(function(event){
    var $this = $(event.target),
        id = $this.attr('id');

    if($('#'+id+'t').is(':visible')){ // To not slide up and down if clicking an already open element.
        $this.parent().children('div').slideUp();
    } else {
        $this.parent().children('div').slideUp();
        $('#'+id+'t').slideToggle();
    }    
});
```

as seen in [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdx20uqe/9/). This hides the content inside the same stage when you click a header, assuming you follow the same naming convention throughout your entire html code.

I would however recommend, if you can, to perhaps clean up your html a little.

---

Look at [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdx20uqe/6/) for an example.

Unless your code has to have your current structure, I would recommend refactoring it into using similar classes and as such be able to write cleaner code.

```
$('.header').click(function(event){
    var $this = $(event.target);
    $this.siblings().slideToggle();
    $this.parent().siblings().children('.content').slideUp();
});
```

Would with the structure in the jsFiddle html provide you with the functionality you want.

Comment: This does not close the first container when the second container is opened. Its probably due to the use of `.siblings()` that only traverses down the DOM

Comment: It does so for me. Are you certain? It only closes siblings in the same stage div, as requested in the comments on the original post.

Comment: after I cleaned up the HTML, works perfectly - I just got rid of the two div containers, and have all toggles under one main one. Thanks Robin, such an elegant solution!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in simple way. You can do it as follows. its just one function written. But it is simple and line of code will be increased

```
$( "#details-2" ).click(function() {    
     $( "#location-2t").hide( "slow");
     $( "#jersey-2t").hide( "slow");
     $("#details-2t").show("slow");
});
```

For more complex div structure and the Ids are in the same format as you have specified in your sample code following code will be very useful.

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("div h2").click(  
        function() {        
            var thisId = $(this).attr("id");
            $("#"+thisId+"t").show("slow");    
            $(this).siblings("div").not($("#"+thisId+"t")).hide("slow");
        });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: It will be amazingly good code for mentioned 60 headers/blocks. About 3840 lines of code.